# why css tooltips don't appear and disappear when tapping over and outside the link on Safari for iOS?

Tags: css, ios

I have duplicated this script for W3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip_bottom

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<h2>Bottom Tooltip</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

On Safari for iOS, it's almost impossible to display the tooltip on tap (and to make it disappear when tapping on the white background page).

However, when I access the w3schools webpage from Safari for iOS, it works perfectly.

Looking into the source page, there are some scripts called, one of them being

If I just add this line, with functions escaping console errors, suddenly the tooltip works perfectly on Safari for iOS.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.snigelweb.com/pub/w3schools.com/snhb-loader.min.js"></script>
<h2>Bottom Tooltip</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

Why? The script calls a file that has absolutely nothing related to the demo.

Thanks a lot for your help :) I'd really like to keep a pure CSS code using tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onclick to the body tag is a workaround: https://dev.webonomic.nl/fixing-the-iphone-css-hover-problem-on-ios